# Boolean value remains false after the value of the static field involved changes

Tags: java, enums, static, boolean, enumset

In my assignment I have to use an `enum` to make an `EnumSet` of elements that fit the criteria given. So, the code needs to be as flexible as possible and allow any criteria that could be applied to the object declared in the `enum`.

I've been testing things out, my code involves taking the finals of the `enum` into the static context, so that a `boolean` can be applied to them, and then looping through each declared object in the `enum` to see if they fit the criteria. For some reason though, the state of the `boolean` doesn't change to `true`, when the value of the static fields fit the criteria.

Here is my code:

```
public class test {
// enumeration of persons by age and sex
    enum Name {
        
        Adam("Male", 17),
        Amy("Female", 24),
        Boris("Male", 12),
        Bella("Female", 16);
        
        final String _sex;
        final int _age;
// static variants to "turn" values to the static context
        volatile static String sex = "";
        volatile static int age = 0;
        
        Name(String sex, int age) {
            _sex = sex;
            _age = age;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
// creating a set of people older than 17
        EnumSet<Name> set = makeSet(Name.age >= 17);
        System.out.print(set.toString());
    }
    static EnumSet<Name> makeSet(boolean query) {
        EnumSet<Name> set = EnumSet.noneOf(Name.class);
        for (Name element : Name.values()) {
// this is the "turning" of the values to the static context
            Name.sex = element._sex;
            Name.age = element._age;
// PROBLEM LIES HERE
// the query remains false, even when age is above 17
            if (query) {
                set.addAll(EnumSet.of(element));
            }
        }
        return set;
    }
}
```

Changing the static fields to `volatile` doesn't fix the problem either, so I don't think it's a caching issue.

*So, why does the boolean not update? Is there a work-around?*

Comment: You are mixing things: volatile can be useful in a multiple threads context, which is clearly not your use case. So you can remove that bit, it's not doing anything here.

Comment: The `boolelan` value `query` is just that: a `boolean` value, not a predicate that can be appliled to some given `Name`. If we wanted to have such a predicate, we would pass along a parameter of type `Predicate<Name>`, e.g. `..makeSet(name -> name.age >= 17)`.

Comment: I do not understand the ratio behind the static fields `name` and `sex`. Could you clarify why you need them?

Comment: @Turing85 There is no relation, I could've identified the `enum` as `Person` as well, that would've probably been clearer. Anyway, your idea of using `Predicate<Name>` worked, so thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answered in comments by @Turing85*

The problem occurred because the `boolean` is being passed by value.
Using a `Predicate` instead of just a `boolean` fixed the problem, because the object reference would be passed on instead, allowing the value to change after the `makeSet()` method was invoked.

Furthermore, this eliminates the need to take the finals of the `enum` into the static context.

Here is my code now:

```
public class test {
// enumeration of persons by age and sex
    enum Name {
        
        Adam("Male", 17),
        Amy("Female", 24),
        Boris("Male", 12),
        Bella("Female", 16);
        
        final String sex;
        final int age;
        
        Name(String sex, int age) {
            this.sex = sex;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
// creating a set of people older than 17
        EnumSet<Name> set = makeSet(query -> query.age >= 17);
        System.out.print(set.toString());
    }
    static EnumSet<Name> makeSet(Predicate<Name> query) {
        EnumSet<Name> set = EnumSet.noneOf(Name.class);
        for (Name element : Name.values()) {
// PROBLEM FIXED
            if (query.test(element)) {
                set.addAll(EnumSet.of(element));
            }
        }
        return set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that the `predicate` (`Name.age >= 17`) is checked at the moment of the function call:

When you are calling `makeSet(Name.age >= 17)`, what actually happens is, the `predicate` returns a boolean, which at the time of checking returns `false`, and `false` is therefore parsed into the function.